Boundary behavior of a Riemann mapping
(Exercise #4 from Michael Taylor's Introduction to Complex Analysis) Let $R\subset \mathbb{C}$ be the open rectangle with vertices at $-1$, $1$, $1+ip$, and $-1+ip$. $D$ is the open unit disk in $\mathbb{C}$. Let $\phi: \bar{R} \rightarrow \bar{\mathbb{D}}$ be the Riemann mapping function such that
$$
\phi(-1)=-i, \quad \phi(0)=1, \quad \phi(1)=i.
$$
Show that $\phi(ip)=-1$.
I know that, as stated in the previous exercise of the book, $\phi$ is uniquely determined by $\phi(-1)=-i, \quad \phi(0)=1, \quad \phi(1)=i$, which implies that we should be able to determine the image of $ip$. However, I am having a hard time to do that.
I have attempted several different approaches, such as using Schwarz reflections, cross ratios, somehow introducing arc length on the boundary,..  but failed to make any one work. Since the book has not discussed Schwarz-Christoffel mappings until this point, I'd like to find a solution without referencing those.
Am I missing something important about Riemann mappings?

What do you think? What did you try to solve it?

I am stumped. Could use some hint.

Ok, here is what I have come up with. Please let me know what you think.
$$ 
L_y: \bar{R}\rightarrow \bar{R}, z\mapsto -\bar{z}
$$ is an antiholomorphic diffeomorphism on $\bar{R}$, just as taking conjugate is an antiholomorphic diffeomorphism on $\bar{D}$,
$$
L_x: \bar{D}\rightarrow \bar{D}, z\mapsto \bar{z}.
$$
It follows that
$L_x\circ \phi \circ L_y: \bar{R} \rightarrow \bar{D}$ is also a Riemann mapping continuously extended to include the boundary. Moreover, we also have
$$
L_x \circ \phi \circ L_y(−1)=-i,\quad 
L_x\circ \phi\circ L_y(0)=1,\quad
L_x\circ \phi \circ L_y(1)=i.
$$
Therefore,
$$
L_x\circ \phi \circ L_y = \phi.
$$
It then follows that the fixed points of $L_y$ must be sent to the fixed points of $L_x$ by $\phi$. Since $ip$ is the only other boundary point of $\bar{R}$ than $0$ that is a fixed point of $L_y$, we must have $\phi(ip)=-1$ as $-1$ is the only fixed point of $L_x$ on $S^1$ other than $1$.
